# No such entity with customerId magento2

Tags: product, magento2.4.5, product-detail-page

Product page- I got an error after upgrade version 2.4.3 to 2.4.5

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with customerId = 

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with customerId = 
<pre>#1 Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry->retrieve() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository.php:402]
#2 Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository->getById() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the error A lot of people facing in the exception.log, everything is working fine but it's difficult to trace this error and fix it, try to apply to try to catch where you can see that this issue will occur or use this solution:

```
<move element="cart.summary" destination="checkout.cart.container" before="checkout.cart.widget" />
```

This will fix your error and if you need anything else let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this issue, please open the file

```
vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php
```

and at the beginning of the `__construct` method temporary add debug backtrace code:

```
foreach (debug_backtrace() as $_stack) { echo ($_stack["file"] ? $_stack["file"] : '') . ':' . ($_stack["line"] ? $_stack["line"] : '') . ' - ' . ($_stack["function"] ? $_stack["function"] : ''); } exit();
```

**example**

```
public function __construct(Phrase $phrase = null, Exception $cause = null, $code = 0) { foreach (debug_backtrace() as $_stack) { echo ($_stack["file"] ? $_stack["file"] : '') . ':' . ($_stack["line"] ? $_stack["line"] : '') . ' - ' . ($_stack["function"] ? $_stack["function"] : ''); } exit(); if ($phrase === null) { $phrase = new Phrase('No such entity.'); } parent::__construct($phrase, $cause, $code); }
```

Comment: https://blog.expertrec.com/magento-2-no-such-entity-with-customerid/#:~:text=If%20you%20receive%20the%20error,via%20Magento%202%20Repository%20Class.